# In Python how can i automatically include the current UTC date in the file name that beautiful soup looks at

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, utc

I have a python 3 program that looks in an HTML file. That HTML File is automatically created on my pc each day by another program and the file name includes the current date.
Im using beautiful soup to look in it
Currently I stop the program each night and manually change the date before we go into the next day!
So on 180718 UTC I would have this line

```
f = open(‘/home/stats/trade_results_180718_UTC.html’, ‘r’)
```

How can I add code so that it will look for a file with path `(‘/home/stats/trade_results_THECURRENTDATE_UTC.html’)`
I want THECURRENTDATE to change automatically in the file name so my program is always looking in the file for that day. kindly help me to figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily generate the name using [`datetime.datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) input for the current UTC date and use [`datetime.datetime.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format it to match your pattern, e.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

filename = dt.utcnow().strftime("/home/stats/trade_results_%y%m%d_UTC.html")
print(filename)  # /home/stats/trade_results_180718_UTC.html
# open(filename, "r") ...
```